XCode localizable.xcstrings - key with parameters
I'm new to XCode and iOS app development and I'm struggling with the localizations strings. I'm using XCode Version 15.3 and would like to know how to use a key with 2 or more parameters in the localizable.xcstrings file.
In a swift file I'm using a Text like this:
let numberOfDays = 2
let numberOfHours = 15

Text("You made \(numberOfDays) days and \(numberOfHours) hours.")

For the string with the 2 parameters in the Text() I would like to use a key, e.g. homeview.detail.information in the localizable.xcstrings file. But I don't know how to put the parameters in the key column of the file to make the translation/localization work.
I tried to put the key followed by %lld like this in the key colum
homeview.detail.information %lld %lld 

and in the english column the text like this:
You made %lld days and %lld hours

But the key is shown in the UI not the "You made ...." text :-(

Remove the \( and ) in the translation. In Text(...) use the Key.

hey @Larme, thanks for the answer. When I use the just key in the Text() like Text("homeview.detail.information") then the key is shown in the UI not the translation text :-(

What's they key? Look at the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/localizing-and-varying-text-with-a-string-catalog

I know this documentation page :-). But it does not show how to use a key with 2 parameters in the localizable.xcstrings

One, two or more, it's the same logic behind it. Tell us what's the current key you have.

As described above. I want to replace the string with 2 parameters in the following text
Text("You made (numberOfDays) days and (numberOfHours) hours.")
by a key like: homeview.detail.information to be able to use it in the Text() like
Text("homeview.detail.information")
And in the localizable.xcstrings I want to use the key "homeview.detail.information" with the 2 parameters from the string

Key: homeview.detail.information %lld %lld, Translation: You made %lld days and %lld hours. Use: Text("homeview.detail.information \(numberOfDays) \(numberOfHours)")?

That's should be the working basic, but in reality, you should order the parameters in localization because the order might differ in languages: You made %1$lld days and %2$lld hours. by adding N$ where N is the place...

Thank you @larme for your patient. And I tested what you suggested. The result in the UI ist: homeview.detail.information 2 15 . The key is being shown in the UI not the translation text

I've tested in a sample app and it worked. Check if there is no extra character (space, etc.), space etc wrong?

I checked for extra characters etc. But there are no extra characters. BUT it is working now :-) What helped was to edit the localizable.xcstrings file as "source code" meaning as text file. I put the key and the translations the way you suggested and now it indeed works :-). THANK you for your help @Larme
